# How can you programmatically change glyphicon elements on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have built a web page that takes form data. It uses bootstrap to expand and collapse sections of the form. The collapsing and expanding works both manually and programmatically.

What doesn't work is changing the glyphicon via events.

The following code works on the desktop but not on an iPhone.

```
$('.collapse').on(
    'shown.bs.collapse', function()
    {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-right").removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-right").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
    }
).on(
    'hidden.bs.collapse', function()
    {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom").removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-right");
    }
);
```

Is there a way to change the glyphicons via code on Safari on an iPhone?

Comment: Could you post a working example? Your solution works on other platforms but not iPhone?

Comment: Works on Android, MacOSX but not iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an edge case. It worked on later versions of iOS Safari.